# Retraction option for flags

Tags: feature-request

I flagged [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88266/3066) because I mis-read it and thought it was a thank-you answer and not a real one. I know my flag will be rejected and rightly so, but I wish I could have retracted it myself. The close-vote pop-up allows retraction, I request the flagging pop-up be given the same feature.